# How does the SAX parser process characters?

Tags: python, xml

I wrote a little code to parse a XML file, and want to print it's characters, but each character seems invoke `characters()` callback function three times.

code：

```
def characters(self,chrs):
            if self.flag==1:
                    self.outfile.write(chrs+'\n')
```

xml file:

```
<e1>9308</e1>
<e2>865</e2>
```

and the output is like below, many blank lines.

```
9308


865
```

I think it should like:

```
9308

865
```

Why there are space line? and I read the doc info:

> characters(self, content)
>
> Receive notification of character data.
>   The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of
>   character data. **SAX parsers may return all contiguous
>   character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into
>   several chunks;** however, all of the characters in any single
>   event must come from the same external entity so that the
>   Locator provides useful information.

so SAX will process one character area as several fragments? and callback several times?

Comment: and the output is like below, many blank lines.
<space line>
9308
<space line><space line>
865

I think it should like:
9308
865

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example XML you posted is obviously not the full XML, because that would be malformed (and the SAX parser would tell you that instead of producing your output). So I'll assume that there's more to the XML than you showed us.

You need to be aware that **every** whitespace between any XML elements is character data. So if you have something like that:

```
<foo>
  <bar>123</bar>
</foo>
```

Then you have at least 3 text nodes: one containing `"\n  "` (i.e. one newline, two space characters), one containing `"123"` and last but not least another one with `"\n"` (i.e. just a newline).

Comment: thanks, I know what happend now. I will erase the space manually.

Answer (score 0):

> so SAX will process one character area as several fragments? and callback several times?

This is obviously happening in your case - any doubt?

But your problem description is poor since you did not mention which parser you are exactly using.

Comment: hi, I use xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler as my hanlder, is this the reason? how can I get pure characters?

Answer (score 0):

Using `self.outfile.write(chrs+'\n')` you don't have a chance of seeing exactly what is happening.

Try `self.outfile.write("Chrs: %r\n" % chrs)`

Look up the built-in function `repr()` ... `"%r" % foo` produces the same as `repr(foo)`; both constructs are very useful in error messages and when debugging.